# mouseMove to element and scroll down 100 px more from that element

Tags: protractor

I have the following test page - https://testnewsnippetcom.000webhostapp.com/test_scroll.html

I would like to go to number 15 and scroll down 100 px more from the number. Is it possible to do this with protractor only. I can execute it with JavaScript but would be nice to do it only by protractor actions.

```
  it('Test MouseMove', async (done) => {

    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    await browser.get('https://testnewsnippetcom.000webhostapp.com/test_scroll.html');
    await browser.actions().mouseMove($('body > p:nth-child(38)')).mouseMove({x: 0, y: 100}).perform();
    await browser.sleep(15000);
    done();

  });
```

The test above scrolls only to 15 but the extra 100 pixels are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it should be possible. This is the example from official [protractor page](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions)

```
browser.actions().
    mouseMove(element).
    mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).
    doubleClick().
    perform();
```

Basically you're doing the same thing, however, the example was given chaining promises before `async/await` came into play. My assumption is your code doesn't work because you can't resolve the chain with `await`. What you should do is write a function like so:

```
async function scrollDownFromElement($element, offset) {
  await browser.actions().mouseMove(element).perform();
  await browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 50, y: offset}).perform();
}
```

And then call it:

```
await scrollDownFromElement($('body > p:nth-child(38)'), 100);
```

I've not had a chance to test it... Since I'm doing it this way (which you don't want to utilize)

```
scroll ($element, offsetY = 0) => browser.executeScript(
        `arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
        window.scroll(
            0,window.scrollY-50-(${offsetY})
        );`,
        $element.getWebElement()
    )
```

Comment: I think that is expected, since it just moves the mouse